# how to display the last added row in the top of the jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello I have a question I want to know if is there a way to display the last added row at the top of jTable in runtime I updated the select statement "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC" which fills my table but the recent added row show up at the bottom of the table till I close the program and I open it again then it shows up at the top

TableItemsModel:

```
public class TableItemsModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    
    ItemsDao itemDao = new ItemsDao();
    private List<Items> items;

    public TableItemsModel() throws Exception {
        this.items = (ArrayList<Items>)itemDao.getItemsList();
    }   
    
    private DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Items item = items.get(rowIndex);
        switch(columnIndex){

            case 0: return p.getProductName();
            case 1: return p.getProductCategory();
            case 2: return p.getProductPrice();
            default: return "";
                
        }
    }
    
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        switch(column){

            case 0: return "PRODUCT NAME";
            case 1: return "PRODUCT CATEGORY";
            case 2: return "PRICE";
            default: return "";
        }
    }
    
    public void addRow(Items item){
        items.add(item);
        fireTableRowsInserted(items.size()-1, items.size()-1);
    }
    
    public void deleteRow(Items item){
        items.remove(item);
        fireTableRowsInserted(items.size()-1, items.size()-1);
    }  
}
```

jFrame:

```
private final TableItemsModel model;

    public Products() throws Exception {

        this.model = new TableItemsModel();

 private void btnAddItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    
        String productName = txtProductName.getText();
        String productCategory = txtProductCategory.getText();
        int productPrice = Integer.valueOf(txtPrice.getText());
        
        try {
            int count = ItemsDao.getInstance().insert(itemDao);
            if (count == 1) {
                model.addRow(Items);
    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"item successfully added");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot Add Item");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddNewPatient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   } 
}
```

Comment: *but the recent added row show up in the bottom of the table* - use the `insertRow(...)` method of your DefaultTableModel to insert the row at the top.

Comment: public void addRow(Item item){
        Items.add(item);
        fireTableRowsInserted(Items.size()-1, Items.size()-1);
    } This is the method which add rows and update the table how can I do so ?

Comment: Update: the full code added, can you tell me how to include the method insertRow into my code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why are you calling your custom object `Items`. That is plural. Objects should be given the singular version of the name. So a better name would be `Item` or maybe even `Product`, since you use "product" in all you method names. Be consistent.

> can you tell me how to include the method insertRow into my code please

You are using a `List` to hold the data. Read the `List` API and you will see that there are two `add(...)` methods. One method adds the element at the end of the `List` and the other method inserts the element at the specified index of the `List`.

So to add an Item at the beginning of the `List` you would specify 0 as the index.

To do this you copy the logic of your addRow(...) method except you want two parameters:

```
public void insertRow(int index, Item item)
```

Then you change the logic in the method to:

1. insert the Item at the specified index of the List.
2. invoke the fireTableRowsInserted(..) method at the specified index.

By passing in the index you make the method very flexible. You can insert an Item at the start or in the middle (if required).