# How to remove row from table after deleting the the product?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello when I delete a product from database through a table using a popupMenu (Right click Button) the row still shows up in the table list, the insertProduct method is working fine and inserts the row to table but the removeProduct method doesn't work can you tell me where is the problem in my code please ?

ProductTable.java:

```
public class ProductTable extends AbstractTableModel {

ProductsDao pd = new ProductsDao();
private final List<Products> products;

public ProductTable() throws Exception {
    this.patients = (ArrayList<Products>) pd.getProductsList();

}

private String[] columnNames = {"PRODUCT NAME", "PRODUCT CATEGORY", "PRODUCT PRICE"};

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return products.size();
}
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        Products p = products.get(row);
        switch (column)
        {
            case 0: return p.getProductName();
            case 1: return p.getProductCategory();
            case 2: return p.getProductPrice();
       
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        Products p = products.get(row);

        switch (column) {

        case 0: p.setProductName((String)value); break;
        case 1: p.setProductCategory((Date)value); break;
        case 2: p.setProductPrice((int)value); break;

        }

        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }
    
    public Products getProduct(int row) {
        return products.get(row);
    }

    public void addProduct(Products p) {
        insertProduct(getRowCount(), p);
    }

    public void insertProduct(int row, Products p) {
        products.add(row, p);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }

    public void deleteProduct(Products p) {
        removeProduct(getRowCount(), p);
    }
    
    public void removeProduct(int row, Products p) {
        products.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }
}
```

JFrame :

```
    public void popupTable() {
    JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Delete", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 
                int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                String cell = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
                Products p = new Products();
                p.setId(cell);
                try {
                    int count = ProductsDao.getInstance().delete(p);
                    if (count == 1) {
                        removeRowFromTable(p);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faild");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AddNewPatient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
    });

    popupMenu.add(menuItem1);
    jTable1.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
}

public static void removeRowFromTable(Products data) {
    ProductTable t = (ProductTable) jTable1.getModel();
    t.deleteProduct(data);
}
```

ProductsDao.java:

```
@Override
    public List<Products> getProductsList() throws Exception {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList<Products> products = new ArrayList<Products>();
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID DESC";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Products product = new Products();
                product.setProductName(rs.getString("PRODUCT_NAME"));
                product.setProductCategory(rs.getString("PRODUCT_CATEGORY"));
                product.setProductPrice(rs.getInt("PRODUCT_PRICE"));
                products.add(product);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            closeConnection(con);
        }
        return products;
    }
```

Comment: (1-) From the answer below: ***... the Products object (which should be renamed Product -- singular)*** - you were given that advice in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65765970/131872. We should not have to take time to repeat suggestions.

Comment: Hello camickr I have changed it to singular thanks for your help last time

Answer (score 2):

These methods don't make sense I'm afraid:

```
public void deleteProduct(Products p) {
    removeProduct(getRowCount(), p);
}

public void removeProduct(int row, Products p) {
    products.remove(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

since you never really use the Products parameter, `p`, in any useful way to identify where it is in the table model. Also, I'm not really sure why you have two methods, and what they are each supposed to represent.

Instead, assuming that `products` in your TableModel is an `ArrayList<Products>`, and assuming that you've overridden Products equals and hashCode methods appropriately, you need to find the index of the selected item in the list and then remove it from the list and notify the listeners that this has been performed. Something like:

```
public void deleteProduct(Products p) {
    int row = products.indexOf(p);
    products.remove(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

This will only work if you override equals and hashCode correctly for Products.

Comment: Hello I have updated ProductTable.java can you a look on it please

Comment: @Meriam: my recommendations are unchanged. You still haven't explained those two methods that I mentioned, why you've written them the way you have, why you ignore the Products parameter.

Comment: I though this way it would dissolve this problem I'm beginner in java programming lol I have changed the method to public void deleteProduct(Products p) {  int row = products.indexOf(p);products.remove(row); ireTableRowsDeleted(row, row); } it did not work as well

Comment: I got this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:424)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:501) .......

Comment: Meaning when you check the ArrayList for the Products object (which should be renamed Product -- singular) the list can't find the item within it suggesting that you've not overridden equals and hashCode properly in the class. You never show us this so only can guess. But it is something that I mentioned twice in my answer but you never touch upon on your question or comments.

Comment: The Products List is filled from database I have updated the code, I have included the ProductsDao.java

Comment: (1+) for suggesting the OP needs to override "equals(...)" and "hashcode()" method of the "Product" class.

Comment: Overriding equals and hashcode method First time I know this since I am beginner thanks for warning me, I'm reading about this

Comment: @Meriam: You are asking many questions on this same subject, many of them about basic Java concepts. Perhaps you might be better off learning these basic concepts first before trying to work with more advanced corners of Java such as GUI programming. This could save you (and us) much frustration and wasted time